# Will iPad2 app work on iPad3?

Tags: ios, iphone-4, iphone-5, ipad-2, ipad-3

I am new to iOS,

I seen that iPad 2 has resolution of `1024-by-768` and iPad 3 has resolution of `2048-by-1536` with retina display..

I am sure that iPad 2 app will defiantly work on iPad mini because the resolution is same..

and same case for iPhone,

Do we need to develop separate app for iPhone 5 ? because it has resolution different then other iPhone..

I am sure this is a dumb question that any mildly experienced iOS developer would laugh at but since a simple Google search didn't turn anything up I figured id ask.

**Any help will be appriciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will iPad2 app work on iPad3?

Yes, it will. The iPad 3 has exactly twice the pixel density in each direction as the iPad 2, so the OS will just go ahead and "scale up" the graphics (except those which are made from images in the app - you'll have to generate a higher resolution version of these image files for iPad 3).

> Do we need to develop separate app for iPhone 5?

Not a separate app, you just have to pay attention to the different screen aspect ratio. If you don't do that, you'll have black bars at the top and the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 4 Apps will work on iPhone 5 :
But it will have black spaces at top and bottom, In order to refactor it you just need to change the splash screen which is suitable for iphone 5.

iPad 2 Apps on iPad3:
It will work without any issues unless they have different iOS versions running in them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the difference between the iPad2 and iPad3 won't be such a big problem. (unless you want to be really exact)

Whereas you should develop a new App for the iPhone5 because it has a greatly different screen format than the iPads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your iPad 2 working app will work on iPad 3 (also, depends on iOS version). Just it will not look good :) In order to make it look good, for all images used for your app, you have to add `@2x` ones with double size.
As for iPhone 5, no, you don't have to develop different app, just you have to make your views resizable to fit on screen. Good Luck!

Comment: Means i need to use better quality of image and i have to append `@2x` to my image name ?

Comment: Not better, but twice bigger, e.g. if you have button image with size `40x40` and filename `btn.png`, for retina support you have to add exact same image with size `80x80` and filename `btn@2x.png`. Same for iPad. GLuck!